# Checking a checkbox based on a database entry on a JSP page

Tags: jsp, jstl

This is my checkbox:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="headC" id="headC" value="Head">
```

I have a String variable `<%=msmtHead%>` which is used to determine if this checkbox is checked or not based on this logic: `If (<%=msmtHead%> !="")` check `else` don't check.

How do I make this work? I have several such checkboxes which need to be checked similarly.

My research tells me JSTL should be used, but I don't know how to use the `<c:if>` tag to test for string values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to let JSP print the `checked` attribute accordingly.

So basically,

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="headC" id="headC" value="Head" <%= ("Head".equals(msmtHead) ? "checked" : "") %>>
```

Or with EL

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="headC" id="headC" value="Head" ${msmtHead == 'Head' ? 'checked' : ''}>
```

Comment: Since msmtHead is a JSP variable, shouldn't it be: ${<%=msmtHead%> == 'Head' ? 'checked' : ''}    ?

Comment: No, you can't mix scriptlets and EL. Let the scriptlet set it as a request attribute like so `request.setAttribute("msmtHead", msmtHead)`. It'll be available as `${msmtHead}`. By the way, the consensus is that scriptlets are poor practice. You should try removing and replacing all scriptlets.