# Checking a checkbox on a JSP page based on List values

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, jstl

I found similar problem: [Checking a checkbox based on a database entry on a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601635/checking-a-checkbox-based-on-a-database-entry-on-a-jsp-page)

I have a Faculty entity and a Subject entity. Every faculty has a list of preliminary subjects. 
So also I have a faculty edit page where I have a checkbox with all subjects.

Let's say I have two collections. One with all the subjects and another with subjects that needed for this faculty.

And when user wants to edit faculty at the start he gets edit page with checked values on subjects where value from faculty subjects equals to value from collection of all subjects.

How this can be achieved ? Or maybe there is a simpler way ?

**EDIT:**

My project is based on `jsp` and `servlets`. I have one servlet which is a `Front Controller` and `Command Pattern` design. So controller calls appropriate `Command`, that performs some work and then returns a path to resource. My Model is dao and transfer objects, they interact with `MySQL` database.

My `facultyEdit.jsp` page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>${faculty.name}</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>${faculty.name}</h1>
    <form id="edit_faculty" action="controller" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="editFaculty" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="oldName" value="${requestScope.name}" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="show" value="false" />
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Faculty name:</label> <input name="name"
                type="text" value="${requestScope.name}" /> <label
                for="budget_seats">Budget seats:</label> <input name="budget_seats"
                type="text" value="${requestScope.budget_seats}" /> <label
                for="total_seats">Total seats:</label> <input name="total_seats"
                type="text" value="${requestScope.total_seats}" />
            <p>
                <label>Preliminary subjects:</label>
            </p>
            ?????
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So the question what to put instead of `?????` to make some of the subjects `ckecked`.

Comment: you should provide more code to help others help you.  behind the jsp, are you using a controller bean?  struts action?  spring mvc controller?  how are you marshalling data to the jsp (model?  pojo? etc.)  this will impact the "how" you are after.

Comment: look into jstl -  c:forEach, c:when tags..